# How to Code the Variance-Stabilized Bootstrap-t Method for Confidence Intervals

Tags: bootstrap

I'm interested in coding up the variance-stabilized bootstrap-$t$ approach for calculation of confidence intervals.  However, I'm a little stuck and could use some help.  I'm coding this in R and this is what I got so far:

```
    data = dataset

    for(i in 1:B){

         boot = sample(nrow(data),replace=TRUE)
         boot_data = data[boot,]
         boot_stat [i]= f(boot_data)

         for(j in 1:M){
             boot_boot = sample(nrow(boot_data),replace=TRUE)
             boot_boot_data = boot_data[boot_boot,]
             boot_boot_stat = f(boot_data)
         }

         se[i] = sum_over_M((boot_boot_stat-est_stat)^2)/(M-1)
    }
```

Now I have B replicates of the se, and need to stabilize them as they're not independent of boot_stat.

```
temp = lowess(se~boot_stat)$y
inv = 1/temp
f = approxfun(boot_stat,inv,yleft=0,yright=0)
int = integrate(f,min(boot_stat),max(boot_stat))
```

Now I'm not sure how to proceed.  I know I need to conduct another bootstrap, but I'm not sure what I'm bootstrapping.  Something to do with the inverse transformation, but I'm still stuck.  Any ideas?